# How to update partial document using pojo with Jest in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Jest client for talking to AWS ES. I want to do a partial update of the existing document in ES and trying to figure out how it can be done using JEST. Seems like JEST does not support partial document update which is specified using "doc":{} tag inside the JSON. For updating partial doc, it looks like application logic will have to first serialize the partial object, then append "doc":{} followed by using the "update.Builder api()" as specified below.

But this does not look to be a clean way.

```
testPojo source = new testPojo(1,"Test");               
try {
    client.execute(new Update.Builder(source).index("twitter").type("tweet").id("1").build());

}catch(Exception e){

}
```

What is the option to update partial document using POJO using JEST ? Looked at similar questions in Stackoverflow but they all talks about "script" and not updates using POJO.